# how to add Class to a template directive element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

i'm new to AngularJs Directive.
what i'm trying to do is , i need to add a simple class into one of my elements in template directive on click.
for example:

```js
var app = angular.module("peykaar",[]);

app.controller('main', function($scope , $rootScope) {

$scope.arry = ["Apple","banana","orange"];

});

app.directive("customCheckbox", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            name:"@"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            var logic = {
                init: function(elem){
                    var self = this;
                    elem.on('click', function(){
                        if ( elem.hasClass('tik')){
                            self.unTik(elem);
                        } else if ( elem.hasClass('untik') ) {
                            self.tik(elem);
                        }
                    });
                },
                tik: function(elem){
                    elem.addClass('custom_checked tik');
                    elem.removeClass('untik');
                },
                unTik:function(elem){
                    elem.removeClass('custom_checked tik');
                    elem.addClass('untik');
                }
            };

            logic.init(element);
            
        },
        template: '<div><span class="custom_checkbox untik"></span><p>{{name}}</p></div>'
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="peykaar" ng-controller="main">

<div class="arry">
  <span ng-repeat="item in arry track by $index" custom-checkbox name="{{item}}" id="$index"></span>
 </div>
  
  </div>
```

so how can i add Class using element.addClass("checked") to span class="custom_checkbox"

Comment: There's a directive for that: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: @J.Titus thank you.
but i need to know how to access to that element from link function.
any help ?

Comment: Sorry, this is beyond my (very) limited knowledge of Angular. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class to fix. Declare a onClick and assign true while clicking.
For example

Var onClick = true;
`<span ng-class={ 'custom' : onClick}></span>`